# Writing values to SQL Database from Fastreport Query

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

I'm a beginer in Fasreport and use a software with fastreport integrated I would like to make a report to allow the user to define 2 parameters on an easy way instead of having to open SQL Manager and change this 2 values by hand. I succeed to make the connexion with the database, request both values and show them on a dialogbox with 2 fields where the user can enter his new values. by validating the dialogbox, I would write both values back in the database. To do that I used a DBquery with the following request

```
UPDATE SupplParams
     SET StartTime = :BTIME, EndTime = :ETIME 
     WHERE ConfigNr = '0'
```

But this doesn't work

If I write the query as follows:

```
UPDATE SupplParams
SET StartTime = '0200', EndTime = '2359' 
WHERE ConfigNr = '0'
```

It works I can also print STIME and ETIME in the report, that means the values of both variables is correct.

I can share the fastreport used if needed.

[image]

Comment: You left out the only vital piece of information.  What kind of database is your data stored in, MS Sql Server, Interbase, Firebird, Access or what?  Also, which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Where is the code that sets the parameter values?

Comment: Looking to the image it's clearly SQL Server @MartynA

Comment: It's a MS SQL Database

Comment: Link for the report:  http://nas.agatech.ch/KeyShot/prive/Acces%20base.fr3

Comment: It is FastReport release 5.6

Comment: You didn't say which Delphi version you are using, but since you are using MS SqlServer, you can use a TAdoConnection from any Delphi version to connect to it and execute your script.  You simply place a TAdoConnection on a Delphi form (or datamodule), configure it to connect to your Sql Server and then execute the script by calling AdoConnection1.ExecSql.  It's literally one line of code (or 2 if you use parameterised Sql).